# RewriteRule isn't working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver, url-rewriting

I'm trying to remove **.php** extension from **.htaccess** . I'm running **Apache** web server on Ubuntu . Have enabled mod_rewrite.c (module) and from virtual host configuration **AllowOverride** option as well

In **.htaccess** I've following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which goes to **404** , but if just try to redirect from specific file to anywhere it is working , that's makes me think that I've problem with code written above , any suggestions ? thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Above code perfectly works for me. I am also using Apache web server on Ubuntu.

Comment: If I try to `RewriteRule index.php http://example.com [R]` this works , but above code doesn't !

Comment: Options -MultiViews after RewriteEngine on

Comment: I have updated my answer. Actually i have created a custom site where i have used htaccess many times for urlwrite but now sry i can't tell u the exact reason.